# certbot is not displaying all the certificates

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am using certbot with nginx plugin. Where I started with `main.domain.com` then I added `subdomain.domain.com` Whenever I issue certbot certificate the later is not displayed. I don't see a folder for subdomain at `/etc/letsencrypt/live` as well. But out of thin air the configuration it works like charm.

The issue is, I am getting a renewal due warning from certbot. Of course no entry at `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal` too.

What do I do now ?

Comment: Does the output of `certbot certificates ` shows the cert?

Comment: @0stone0 Nope, it displays only main.domain.com

Comment: Then there isn't a cert, maybe `subdomain.domain.com` redirects to `main`?

Comment: @0stone0 No, it has a different downstream server and works as expected. But when I issue certbot --nginx I can see all the main and subdomain list